# React pass an event into child component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to find a way to pass event to child component in react.
I have something like that:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component<IProps, IState> {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className={"ParentComponent"} onClick={this.onPageClick}>
            ... some navbar ...
            ... some `tabs` component
            ...
               <ChildComponent/>
               <AnotherChildComponent/>
            ...
            ... some footer ...
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

the child components are actually sub pages (changed using the tabs) with lot of logic and data inside them. (so I prefer manage them in separate components rather then one giant page).

some of the inner component have `Editable` labels which changed into an input (or in other case to a textarea or to MD editor) when the label is clicked.

> there is an inner state in the child components when the user enter
>   into "Edit Mode" of the label. every component can have several of
>   this editable-labels.

The product request is when the user is clicking anywhere in the page the labels should exit from edit mode, so I need to capture the onClick on the master div like in the example and pass somehow the event into a function into the active child component so it will update it's inner state to exit edit-mode (if any).

Now, the solution I thought is to create a state variable in the parent which will be changed by the `onPageClick` function and pass into the child components
so they could update the local state. and then reset it on the parent again.

something like:

```
onPageClick() {
   this.setState({ pageClicked: true }, () => {
      this.setState({ pageClicked: false }
   });
}

...
<ChildComponent pageClicked={this.state.pageClicked}/>
```

But it will change the parent state twice per click (and thus also the child state) even if not neccesary. the ideal why if I'll find a way to pass some event delegate to the children so a function will be triggered only inside the child when the parent onClick is triggered without any state changes in the parent.

Doe's it possible? do anyone have an idea how to implement something like that?

Comment: sounds like a good case to use redux

Comment: You could just use plain javascript and add a listener when the child is in edit mode to check if anything that is not that input (or inside that input) is clicked. Just make sure to remove the listener when done. Also the second argument of set state is invoked immediately - i don't know what you re trying to achieve with that but right not that `onPageClick` function is going to set state twice...

Comment: can you try to improve your question?  The grammar is very poor.  If I was to guess, it sounds like you want to pass a function from parent to child so the child can update parent's state. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making your problem way more complicated than it needs to be.
You shouldn't listen for clicks on the outside component.
Instead, you should use your text input's `onBlur` event.
`onBlur` event is fired whenever a text input loses focus.

Comment: You're awesome. absolutely right and it worked perfectly! great thinking! Thanks!

Comment: I'm super glad I could help